# Why 1000 Rs and 500 Rs not accepted in Bhutan and Nepal?

Tags: currency, optimal-currency-area

In Nepal and Bhutan, Indian rupee is accepted but 500 Rs. And 1000 Rs note is not accepted. Cam there be any specific reason behind this?

Comment: This is a perfectly good question here, but I suspect you'll get better answers over at http://travel.stackexchange.com.